# Syntax error dream weaver

Tags: javascript, dreamweaver

I am a complete noob in javascript and coding in general.

### I recently am getting this syntax error on line 10 in Dreamweaver and don't know why...

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var toptab=new ddtabcontent("tab-a")
toptab.setpersist(true)
toptab.setselectedClassTarget("link") //"link" or "linkparent"
toptab.init()

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

var bottomtab=new ddtabcontent("tab-b")
bottomtab.setpersist(true)
bottomtab.setselectedClassTarget("link") //"link" or "linkparent"
bottomtab.init()

</script>
```

Comment: you're missing `;` on every single one of your lines of code.

Comment: What do you mean, line 10?